# Porto Theme in Magento 2 Doesn't Match Demo Site

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.1, porto-theme

I’m having some issues installing the Porto Theme into Magento 2.3.1. I began installing the theme using the Documentation (as linked above). I uploaded the theme files into my server along with the patches that Porto has added for better functionality. Then I went in and applied the setup:upgrade command and imported my demo of choice. What came out was not an exact replica of the demo I wanted. The header was white and blue, not the black with white text I was expecting.

So then I tried using the Quick Start Package files which ended up taking my site down altogether. Luckily I created a snapshot in DigitalOcean so I could reset things back to the working order. I don’t have any products or customizations yet. I’m wanting to do that after I setup the theme correctly.  But now, I have no idea what I am supposed to do.

Here are some snapshots: [Installation Results](https://snag.gy/8DSFtd.jpg) vs [Desired Demo](https://snag.gy/IsbCuE.jpg)

Comment: i believe you can adjust any settings you need from admin theme design configuration. their demo probably made the same way.

Comment: @MagenX I tried this after installing the Demo, but no matter what I do, it doesn't match the Demo I need.

Comment: Contact the creator via https://themeforest.net/item/porto-ultimate-responsive-magento-theme/9725864. Their support is good.

Comment: My support with them has expired. So, I'm unable to contact them.